# Is there a simple boolean formatter that allows custom content?

Tags: entities

I have a boolean field that stores 0 or 1. I'd like a formatter that lets me enter custom markup to display on 0, and different content to display on 1. I'm happy enough doing this in code, just thought I might be reinventing the wheel if I did.

Answer (score 1):

You can give a try to [custom_formatters](http://drupal.org/project/custom_formatters) in Drupal, this module allows you to do things without writing a code

Comment: Thanks, have never investigated it - will give it a go. It looks like a much more complex module than I was originally thinking about.

Answer (score 1):

Using Boolean Field it allows you to define label for On value using "Use label as On value label" check box as shown in below screen. But, only issue is you cannot define the off value label.

[image]

You can use list (integer) type field to achieve the same functionality by selecting widget types as check-box/radio-buttons. In the allowed options you can set Key|Label pairs easily. That should work!

Comment: Thanks, I'm aware of the first point (which is a fairly poor attempt at allowing customisation imho). I hadn't considered using a list, and that would work nicely I think. It feels a bit ugly changing the type of field to fit my formatter needs however...

Answer (score 0):

<s>Not directly related, as it **wont allow users** to display **custom html**, but it's good enough for some cases (and saves you writing a module!).</s> My bad! it supports custom output.

[boolean_formatter](http://drupal.org/project/boolean_formatter) has several nice *formatters* for *boolean fields*, check it on modules page.

It behaves like views's boolean formatter which can be used for psudo fields such as is *node sticky* or is *published* but not with Field API boolean fields :|